# Real-time conversion of modeling files (skp etc) into prefab file format (in which you can add components)

Tags: unity-game-engine, runtime, modeling

i want Real-time conversion of modeling files (skp etc) into prefab file format (in which you can add components) without Unity Editor.

1. is there a another tool or asset?
2. can i use UnityEditor.PrefabUtility.createPrefab() method with out using UnityEditor class?

help me please..

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Are you planning on importing models at run time?

Comment: PhotonNetwork.Instiate() suported only prefab . so i want make prefab at run time